# PHP retrieving array values using dash arrow "->"

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework2

I've been using PHP quite a while now, but never been an advanced programmer. I feel like this is dumb question but never understood why some array values can be retrieved using different methods:

This:

```
$array->value
```

rather than normal:

```
$array['value']
```

The standard $array['value'] always works, but the one using the -> method doesn't at times. Why is that?

Here's an example.  I am using Zend Framework 2 and I can grab a session value using the -> method:

```
$this->session->some_value
```

However, I can't if I do a new, normal array:

```
$array = array('some_value' => 'myvalue');
$array['some_value']; // works!!
$array->some_value;  // does not work :(
```

In Zend Framework 1 most arrays would work fine this way, and in ZF2 more and more , I run into issues where I need to change the way I get that value.
Does this make sense?  I sure appreciate any help. 
Thanks,
Greg

Comment: Thanks to all for the great answers. You are all right about what I was looking for. Voitcus (below) had the key to help me understand better. Thank you,everyone, for the help!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As stated before in other answers, using `->` means you are accessing an object, not an array.

However, it is sometimes possible that an object would be treated as an array. It is when it is implementing [`ArrayAccess`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface. The coder can do such that eg. calling `$object->field` would be equivalent to `$object['field']`, but he/she must not.

Moreover, it is possible to treat an array as an object (refer [to the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php)), however in this case it is not an array but an object and is the same way as above.

Comment: This is what I thought and is exactly what I was looking for, just didn't know the exact reasons.  PHP's ArrayObject, I think, is what caused my confusion when using ZF 1 or 2, as the objects mostly looked  and behaved like array's.  Now I get it! Yay!  After reading your comment and linked doc, I found this page which helped my understanding as well. Thanks!!
[http://codingexplained.com/coding/php/zend-framework/using-sessions-in-zend-framework-2](http://codingexplained.com/coding/php/zend-framework/using-sessions-in-zend-framework-2)

Answer (score 2):

The variables that allow you get properties with `->` are actually objects, not arrays. They do allow the `['some_key']` syntax, but that doesn't mean they are arrays. They are not.

You can reading more about objects [on this page of the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php).

Answer (score 2):

To make it happened just using a stdclass cast

```
$optionsType = array(
    (object)  array("text" => "Virtual Account", "value" => "TOPUPVA"),
```

and you could access it by

```
foreach($optionsType as $key=>$value){
    var_dump($value->text);
```

As stated by Voitcus answer

> using -> means you are accessing an object, not an array.

so if you insists to use dash arror (->) than you can casting your array to object (which is make your program consume more memory)

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't arrays, they're [objects](http://php.net/manual/language.types.object.php).

Answer (score 1):

That is because it is not an array it is an objects variable.

For example;

```
class MyObject{

   var $myVariable = 'test';

}

$MyObject = new MyObject();
echo $MyObject->myVariable; // Would return 'test'
```