# Wordpress translation file also translate text in css files

Tags: css, wordpress, language-translation

I'm setting up a translate file for my website. I noticed that even the text in the CSS frontend file is translated, which broke my CSS theme.

Here is the CSS portion of code :

```
.wpem-tbl-status.Confirmed {
    background-color: #0daf0b;
}
```

When I inspect the webpage in the console, I get something like :

```
<span class="wpem-tbl-status translated_Confirmed">translated_Confirmed</span>
```

When I want to have :

```
<span class="wpem-tbl-status Confirmed">translated_Confirmed</span>
```

Here is the wordpress code incriminated :

```
<td data-title="<?php _e( 'Status', 'wp-event-manager-registrations' ); ?>">
    <span class="wpem-tbl-status <?php echo ( $wp_post_statuses[ get_post_status( $registration_id ) ]->label); ?>">
    <?php echo esc_html( _e( $wp_post_statuses[ get_post_status( $registration_id ) ]->label, 'wp-event-manager-registrations' ) ); ?>
    </span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you should be aware of ...

##### Always escape your output, even for attributes

Use `esc_attr__()` **to return** the translated value
or `esc_attr_e()` **to echo** the translated
value. If you do not need a translation, just
use `esc_attr()` / `echo esc_attr()`.

##### How to pass variables inside translation functions

You can't translate text if you actually don't know what that text
is. [According to the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/translate/), you must pass a string, **you can’t
translate variables**.

Therefore this **does not** work: `_e( 'Current status:' . $status, 'my-text-domain' );`

**The solution:** use [sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to insert variables inside strings.

```
echo sprintf( __( 'Current status: %s', 'my-text-domain' ), $status );
```

##### Avoid double echoing

So, instead of (see line 3 in your code snippet): `echo esc_html( _e( ... ) );`
do something like: `esc_html_e( .... );`

Doing the same:
`esc_html_e( 'Blablabla' );`
`echo esc_html__( 'Blablabla' );`

**Read more about the differences here:**
`__()` - return translated string [[docs]](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/)
`_e()` - echo translated string [[docs]](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_e/)
`_n()` - return translated singular/plural form of a string based on supplied number [[docs]](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_n/)
`_x()` - return translated string with gettext context [[docs]](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_x/)
`_ex()` - echo translated string with gettext context [[docs]](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_ex/)
`esc_html__()` - escape and return translated string for safe use in HTML output [[docs]](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html__/)
`esc_html_e()` - escape and echo translated string for safe use in HTML output [[docs]](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html_e/)
`esc_html_x()` - escape and return translated string with gettext context for safe use in HTML output [[docs]](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html_x/)
`esc_attr__()` - escape and return translated string for safe use in an attribute [[docs]](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr__/)
`esc_attr_e()` - escape and echo translated string for safe use in an attribute [[docs]](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr_e/)
`esc_attr_x()` - escape and return translated string with gettext context for safe use in an attribute [[docs]](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr_x/)

##### Finally, your code should look something like this

```
<?php  

$domain = 'wp-event-manager-registrations';
$status = $wp_post_statuses[ get_post_status( $registration_id ) ]->label;  

if ( strtolower( $status ) === 'confirmed' ) {
    $status_i18n = __( 'Confirmed', $domain );
} else {
    $status_i18n = __( 'Not Confirmed', $domain );
}  

?>

<td data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Status', $domain ); ?>">
  <span class="wpem-tbl-status <?php echo esc_attr( $status ); ?>">
  <?php echo sprintf( esc_html__( 'Status: %s', $domain ), $status_i18n ); ?>
  </span>
</td>  

<!-- Alternatively - if you only want to output the value (without further text) -->  

<td data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Status', $domain ); ?>">
    <span class="wpem-tbl-status <?php echo esc_attr( $status ); ?>">
    <?php echo esc_html( $status_i18n ); ?>
    </span>
</td>
```

**Also make sure** that the value of `$status` has not already been translated elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Thank you for all the precisions. Indeed, the plugin add weird coding. However, these changes does not change the output. It seems that you have right on the last sentence, $status` is translated before. Now I need to find where...

Comment: Ferris, I dont understand the syntax `$wp_post_statuses[ get_post_status( $registration_id ) ]->label;` however. When I print `get_post_status( $registration_id )` it is in english and should work for the attribute. I looked in the files and `$wp_post_statuses` is never defined. As far as I understand, we are here filling an array with the values. What does the `->label` do ? Can find anything online.

Comment: `$wp_post_statuses(array)` - It's a global variable of WordPress, an array of data about all the statuses of entries. publish, future, etc. ..... see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_statuses/

Comment: `->` indicates that an object is accessed. In some cases objects can be treated as an array. See here for a good explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16629432/20896315

Comment: Do a `var_dump( $wp_post_statuses[ get_post_status( $registration_id ) ] )`. Maybe you find your required (untranslated) value. Makes sense that `->label` is already translated.

Comment: I managed to make it work, thx !